# Как переместить кнопку в html

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно переместить кнопки в правую часть header, уже перепробовал много способов, ничего не получается, прошу о помощи.

HTML:

```
<body> 
    <header class="rasselstudio">RasselStudio
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Про нас</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Управление БД</button>
    </header>
    <hr>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Буду очень признателен!

Comment: Можно поподробнее в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Я хочу переместить кнопку "О нас" и "Управление БД" влево.
Но не получается, уже и в css и в html дописывал код, ничего не получается

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato ты что-нибудь понял??

Comment: @ПростаMiha Ну извините, я плохо объясняю

Comment: Кароче проблема в том что кнопка не хочет перемещаться влево

Comment: Вправо***** Я ошибся, блин

Comment: Типо что бы было: RasselStudio______________"Кнопка"  "Кнопка"

Comment: @ПростаMiha  xD я и думаю, то ли я дурак, то ли сани не едут, вроде слева.... думаю о чем же автор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так или как?

```css
.rasselstudio{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="rasselstudio">
    <span>RasselStudio</span>
  <div class="btn-block">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Про нас</button>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Управление БД</button>
   <div>
  </header>
  <hr>
</body>
```

Comment: Нет, вот так:
Rassel Studio_____________"О нас" "Управление БД"

Comment: я переделал, может так?

Comment: Да!! Именно так!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: господи сколько сложного `css` :) а просто `float: right` нонче не в почете? :)

Comment: @phpBear я думаю float это плохая практика

Comment: @phpBear Не думаю, но уже все решилось

Comment: @ПростаMiha Поставил, спасибо ещё раз за помощь

Comment: @ПростаMiha о как... то есть куча избыточного кода лучше чем более простое решение? ;)

Comment: @ПростаMiha я начинал с flex'ов, поэтому привычка иногда осталось пихать их в код, но действительно почему float так плох?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato ну я где-то прочитал что использовать float это уже не так практично как раньше, и лучше его не импользовать

Comment: может меня нае...обманули ?!

Comment: @ПростаMiha не обманули, пишут что flex более гибче для макета чем тот же float, как я понял float выдергивает элемент документа из потока, а flex дает работать и по верт и горз, не нарушая иерархию страницы. о как